# Java EE: Payara micro server not generating REST endpoints (404 error)

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, java-ee-8, payara-micro

I am new to Java EE development. I downloaded Payara micro-server 6.2023.8 and generated a simple Java EE application through the maven archetype `com.airhacks:javaee8-essentials-archetype:0.0.4` (https://github.com/AdamBien/javaee8-essentials-archetype).

However, when I deploy the `war` file (generated through `mvn clean package`) on the server through the command:

```
java -jar 'G:\Workspace\payara-micro-6.2023.8.jar' --deploy .\target\javaee-demo.war --port 8080
```

, the REST endpoint (`http://localhost:8080/javaee-demo/resources/ping`) is not exposed and generates a `404` error when accessed via a browser. The only URL present in the logged output against '`Payara Micro URLs`' is `http://localhost:8080/javaee-demo`.

Here's my resource (generated automatically from the archetype used):

```
@Path("ping")
public class PingResource {

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "message")
    String message;

    @GET
    public String ping() {
        return this.message + " Jakarta EE with MicroProfile 2+!";
    }
}
```

Here's my JAX-RS configuration file:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {

}
```

And, here's the (partial) output of running the above command:

```
"Deployed": [
    {
        "Name": "javaee-demo",
        "Type": "war",
        "Context Root": "/javaee-demo"
    }
]
```

`pom.xml` file for reference:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>in.mydemoprojects</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>javaee-demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I looked into the other stackoverflow questions about this, but to no avail. Can someone please help me debug?

Answer (score 0):

I meandered my way around this same problem as below. You may want to try it too:

1. Use jdk-1.8, confirm this by running the command `java -version` on command prompt.
2. If the command returns a different version, then:
   **2.1.** download and install jdk-1.8.
   **2.2.** go to the bin folder created as a result of the installation.
   **2.3.** copy at least (and perhaps, javac, javaw) the file "java.exe" and paste it in the folder (let's call it "folderA") where java looks for executables.
   **2.4.** on my windows machine, the "folderA" is in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath".
   **2.5** run the command in #2 above again, ensure Jdk-1.8.xxx is returned.
3. Download Payara Microedition 5.181 (not version 6.0) from here:
   https://jar-download.com/artifacts/fish.payara.extras/payara-micro/5.181/source-code
4. In your POM file, add the following dependencies:

> dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

5. Attempt to deploy your app on payara again, it should work. There's probably a better solution out there though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue by deploying this simple Java EE application with Payara micro 6.2023.11. The REST end points are not exposed. As a workaround I switched to Payara micro 5.2021.7, ran the same command again and with this version it works.

By the way - I am using OpenJDK 11 - it seems to have nothing to do with the Java version, but that an additional setting and/or annotation is required for Payara micro server 6.2023.11 to make it work with this version too. But since I am also new to programming Java EE and using an application server, I don't know the real reason for the "inconsistency".